# How to get all values in a colum listed in MySql - php

Tags: php, mysql, report

I am a newbie in php and mysql - but almost managed to display data from DB in a html page
I have a table with rows which I managed to read and showed on a page.
All the rows in a burst, - no filtering, nothing!
Now I need to create a drop down list of a column values so that one of them can be selected to show a report it in a table list  format in html.
The data table consists of  entries from  different handheld machines. One column in each row contains the IDs of the machine sending the row/record.
First I need to get all the values in a particular column - say 'MachineID'. But I need to skip repeating entries . One machine will be sending many entries/records.rows, but we need to skip those repetitions while preparing this machine list.

once the drop down list is ready, I can select one and call another php page which shows only data from that machine only.

How to create this list first?

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT` may be what you're looking for here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you I would like to create the same using a dynamic generated form. My code is following :

```
<body><div id="foo">
    <form method="POST" action="">

         <?php  
        $sql="SELECT * FROM table_name";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die ("error selecting from table".mysqli_error($connection));

         echo  "<select name='dropdown' value='' class ='f' ><option>-------------select platform-------------</option>";
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {

            echo "<option value = ".$row['id'].">".$row['your_column_name']."</option>";
        }

        ?>

    </select><br><br>
    <input type= "submit" id= "submit_button" value= "submit form">
</form></div></body>
```

check your connection variable. and other variables. 
hope it helps :) if it does than don't forget to green it :P

Comment: This was the starting point I was looking for and I have successfully used SELECT DISTINCT and extracted the machine IDs and then passed the selected ID through POST and created a report using another page.("action") So far basic purpose is met.

Comment: I am interested in knowing how I can do the task in a single page.
Select options and button on the top of page, - while pressing button , report on a table on the lower side of the same page. Again select another option and press button  - report table changes to new selection.
Is this possible in php? 
How I should proceed?

Comment: there are two methods to do the work.You can submit the form on the same page like this : if(isset($_POST['dropdown'])) {//your logic}  or you can use Ajax to serve the purpose